# How to convert a codepoint to utf-8?

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, c++17, boost-locale

I have some code that reads in an a unicode codepoint (as escaped in a string 0xF00).

Since im using [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), I'm speculating if the following is best (and correct) approach:

```
unsigned int codepoint{0xF00};
boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(&codepoint, &codepoint+1);
```

?

Comment: Do you want to process any codepoint (up to 01FFFFF) or just Basic Multiligual Plance codepoints (up to 0xFFFF)? If former case you will use char16_t to utf8, in the latter char32_t to utf8...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I havent't really decided that yet. The unsigned int was retrieved via a `std::strtol`

Comment: So maybe just, 0xFFFF - I would be interested in the full solution though.. so both solutions can work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, a codepoint in this form is (conveniently) UTF-32, so what you're looking for is a transcoding.

For a solution that does not rely on functions deprecated since C++17, and isn't really ugly, and which also does not require hefty third-party libraries, you can use the very lightweight [*UTF8-CPP*](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) (four small headers!) and its function `utf8::utf32to8`.

It's going to look something like this:

```
const uint32_t codepoint{0xF00};
std::vector<unsigned char> result;

try
{
   utf8::utf32to8(&codepoint, &codepoint + 1, std::back_inserter(result));
}
catch (const utf8::invalid_code_point&)
{
   // something
}
```

(There's also a `utf8::unchecked::utf32to8`, if you're allergic to exceptions.)

(And consider reading into `vector<char8_t>` or `std::u8string`, since C++20).

(Finally, note that I've specifically used `uint32_t` to ensure the input has the proper width.)

I tend to use this library in projects until I need something a little heavier for other purposes (at which point I'll typically switch to ICU).

Comment: This is great solution (using a small header-only library) and so far the best as I see it -and I could probably use that. However, since I already have boost  - I see no reason to change given current needs - and given that it will do what i *expect* it to and theres no cave-at. One reason for asking was also that I find the boost documentation somewhat lacking here or I just couldn't find this one. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @darune Sounds reasonable. BTW it's "caveat", one word :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with the standard library using [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to convert UTF-32 (code points) to UTF-8:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::string codepoint_to_utf8(char32_t codepoint) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(&codepoint, &codepoint + 1);
}
```

This returns a `std::string` whose size is 1, 2, 3 or 4 depending on how large `codepoint` is. It will throw a `std::range_error` if the code point is too large (> 0x10FFFF, the max unicode code point).

---

Your version with boost seems to be doing the same thing. [The documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__codepage.html#ga2de4d9d38004e5d7146abf2bd6a3df0b) says that the `utf_to_utf` function converts a UTF encoding to another one, in this case 32 to 8. If you use `char32_t`, it will be a "correct" approach, that will work on systems where `unsigned int` isn't the same size as `char32_t`.

```
// The function also converts the unsigned int to char32_t
std::string codepoint_to_utf8(char32_t codepoint) {
    return boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(&codepoint, &codepoint + 1);
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder, that `wstring_convert` and `codecvt_utf8` are deprecated since C++17. There are no alternatives in the standard library and current recommendation is to use a dedicated library.

Comment: But yeah the key is that you [accidentally] have UTF-32!

Comment: Hmm, I can't really use this option since it is deprecated in [tag:c++17]. Do you have non-deprecated workaround ? :)

Answer (score 4):

C++17 has deprecated number of convenience functions processing utf. Unfortunately, the last remaining ones will be deprecated in C++20 <sup>(*)</sup>. That being said `std::codecvt` is still valid. From C++11 to C++17, you can use a `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>`, starting with C++20 it will be `std::codecvt<char32_t, char8_t, mbstate_t>`.

Here is some code converting a code point (up to 0x10FFFF) in utf8:

```
// codepoint is the codepoint to convert
// buff is a char array of size sz (should be at least 4 to convert any code point)
// on return sz is the used size of buf for the utf8 converted string
// the return value is the return value of std::codecvt::out (0 for ok)
std::codecvt_base::result to_utf8(char32_t codepoint, char *buf, size_t& sz) {
    std::locale loc("");
    const std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t> &cvt =
                   std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>(loc);

    std::mbstate_t state{{0}};

    const char32_t * last_in;
    char *last_out;
    std::codecvt_base::result res = cvt.out(state, &codepoint, 1+&codepoint, last_in,
                                            buf, buf+sz, last_out);
    sz = last_out - buf;
    return res;
}
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> `std::codecvt` will still exist in C++20. Simply the default instantiations will no longer be `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` and `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` but `std::codecvt<char16_t, char8_t, std::mbstate_t>` and `std::codecvt<char32_t, char8_t, std::mbstate_t>` (note `char8_t` instead of `char`)

Comment: _"char will be replaced with char8_t"_ Potentially misleading statement?

Comment: You wrote `char16_t` not `char32_t` in your demo; deliberate?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, when reading that after your comment it could be misleading. I have edited it (and fixed the stupid 16...). Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Err... English is not my first language, and I could not understand your last comment. I assume *Naaaais* is for nice, but what is *np*?

Comment: It's Internet speak for "no problem".

Answer (score 2):

After reading about the unsteady state of UTF-8 support in C++, I stumbled upon the corresponding C support [`c32rtomb`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c32rtomb), which looks promising, and likely won't be deprecated any time soon

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cuchar>
#include <climits>

size_t to_utf8(char32_t codepoint, char *buf)
{
    const char *loc = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::mbstate_t state{};
    std::size_t len = std::c32rtomb(buf, codepoint, &state);
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
    return len;
}
```

Usage would then be

```
char32_t codepoint{0xfff};
char buf[MB_LEN_MAX]{};
size_t len = to_utf8(codepoint, buf);
```

If your application's current locale is already UTF-8, you might omit the back and forth call to `setlocale` of course.