# How to convert Unicode codepoints stored in uint32_t to a human readable string?

Tags: c++, unicode

Given a Unicode codepoint value stored in a `uint32_t` variable, how can I convert it to a human readable character using C++?

More generally; given an array of `uin32_t` values representing Unicode codepoints - that might belong outside the BMP - how can I convert it to a string of human readable characters?

I tried using `std::string( unicode_arrayIndex.begin(), unicode_str_length)` but it was rendering weird and incorrect when I printed the resulting string on the screen.

Comment: Note: UNICODE is a many-headed beast. If the terminal doesn't know how to render the flavour you have, you'll have to beat it into a flavour the terminal does render.

Comment: A lot depends on the capabilities of the terminal you are using. It may be impossible, I would imagine this is more likely if you are outside the BMP.

Comment: Without knowing any details about your situation I would guess that your best bet to get something to work reasonably portably is to convert your code points to UTF-8 bytes and try to print that.

Comment: `rendering weird`! Were you printing to the terminal? What does your terminal support? Probably UTF-8 but you need to check. Currently, you are simply truncating each 32 bit value into an 8 bit value, that's not going to work for any characters about 127. You need to convert your Unicode Code points into an understood format (probably UTF-8, but others are supported).

Comment: For Windows machines, this link is relevant if not definitive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328697/using-utf-16-for-i-o-with-visual-studio-instead-of-code-pages

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342158/14065

Comment: Standard C++ has nothing.  You'll need to work with what your platform provides.  What platform are you on?

Comment: What do you mean "human readable"? Just the character name? (so the ISO standard). Else forget it. uint32_t is not enough. You may need combining characters (so next 0 to infinity code points), you need previous characters (for ligatures), next characters, information about font (cursive like hand-writting, monospace and block charactes) should be handled differently, and also context (numbers in tables), also languages, preferences, etc. Just use rendering engines so all: pango, harfbuzz, opentype, or other proprietary stuffs). Very complex stack.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has nothing built-in to help you with this. Converting Unicode codepoints to/from various UTF encodings is fairly simple to code by hand, or you should consider getting a good Unicode library, or use platform-specific APIs, to handle the conversions for you.

That being said...

If your target platform uses a 4-byte `wchar_t` type (usable with UTF-32) then you can simply put the codepoint values as-is into a `std::wstring` and display it using `std::wcout`.

Otherwise, you will need to *encode* each codepoint value to its [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) representation and then display it using `std::(u8)string` or `std::wstring`, respectively.  And that is assuming your terminal can even handle those encodings to begin with.

Comment: No need for an entire library to handle codepoint to UTF-8 conversions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987 for a simple function.